# Limit on Poisson distribution

Tags: calculus, probability, limits

What is the limit as $\lambda \to \infty$ Of

> $$\large{e^{-it\sqrt{\lambda}}e^{\lambda(e^{it/\sqrt{\lambda}}-1)}}$$

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite that as 
$$ \begin{eqnarray}
  \lim_{\lambda \to \infty} \exp\left(\lambda \left( \mathrm{e}^{i t/\sqrt{\lambda}} - 1 - i t/\sqrt{\lambda} \right) \right) &=&  \lim_{\lambda \to \infty}\exp\left(-t^2 \cdot \frac{ \mathrm{e}^{i t/\sqrt{\lambda}} - 1 - i t/\sqrt{\lambda} }{-t^2/\lambda} \right) \\
 & \stackrel{u = t/\sqrt{\lambda}}{=}& \lim_{u \to 0} \exp\left(-t^2 \frac{\exp(i u) - 1 - i u}{(i u)^2} \right) \\
 &=& \exp\left(-t^2 \lim_{u \to 0}  \frac{\exp(i u) - 1 - i u}{(i u)^2} \right)
\end{eqnarray}
$$
Now use [L'Hospital's rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule) to finish this off making sure to justify steps above.